# ABCD * 4 = EDCBA, for ABCD and EDCBA integers with all digits different for each case

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What are the numbers $A, B, C, D$ and $E$ that satisfy $ABCD*4=EDCBA$, given that $ABCD$ and $EDCBA$ are two integers whose digits are represented by each of these letters? Different letters represent different numbers.

Well, I know that, for $EDCBA$ to be divisible by 4, $BA$ has to be divisible  by 4. I also know that $A$ has to be greater than 1, since the above multiplication gives us a five digit number. By that, we conclude $A \in \{2, 4, 6, 8\}$. However, I get stuck here, should I test what happens for each of the cases of $A$?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: $A\in \{1,2\}$ as the product is a 5-digit number.  Similar logic will help you find B.

Comment: there are online solvers for this sort of cryptarithm problem. eg. [this](https://www.dcode.fr/cryptarithm-solver) returns 2178*4 = 08712.

Answer (score 1):

I assume leading digit can not be $0$. It is clear that $E = \{1,2,3\}$. We solve one by one.

If $E = 1$, then $A = 3$ or $A=4$ (Convince yourself). $A$ must be even, so $A = 4$. Now, the one digit that multiplied by $4$ ends with $4$ is $1$ or $6$. Since $1$ is taken, $D = 6$.  Observe that if $B > 2$, then the multiplication result will be at least $17000$, impossible. Hence, $B=0$ or $2$ as $1$ is taken. Now, if $B = 2$, considering the $2$ carry in the multiplication, $C = 5$ or $C = 0$. However, quick check reveals none works. If $B = 0$, $C$ must be $2$ or $7$. This also does not work when we work out the math.

If $E = 2$, then $A = 5,6$ or $7$. $A$ must be even, so $A = 6$. Now, the one digit that multiplied by $4$ ends with $6$ is $4$ or $9$. If $D = 4$, then similar logic shows that $B = 0,1$ ($2$ is taken). If $B = 0$, $4C+1$ ends with $0$, which is impossible. If $B = 1$, $C = 0,5$, which also does not work. If $D = 9$, then the maximum possible value of $ABCD \times 4$ is smaller than $29000$, absurd.

If $E=3$, then $A = 7,8,9$. As $A$ is even, $A = 8$. Now, $D$ is either $2$ or $7$. If $D = 7$, then $ABCD \times 4 < 37000$, impossible. If $D=2$, $B$ must be $0$ or $1$. If $B = 0$, $C = 5$, but this does not work. If $B = 1$, $4C$ ends in $1$, impossible.

If leading zeroes are allowed, the only solution is $(2,1,7,8,0)$. There are some added cases, but the method is similar. I attached a python code to verify.

```
for a in range(0,10):
    for b in range(0,10):
        for c in range(0,10):
            for d in range(0,10):
                for e in range(0,10):
                    if len(set([a,b,c,d,e])) == 5:
                        if (1000*a+100*b+10*c+d)*4 == 10000*e+1000*d+100*c+10*b+a:
                            print(a,b,c,d,e)
```

It returns `2 1 7 8 0`, as claimed.